# Как объединить все элементы в коллекции в одну строку и проставить между ними запятую?

Tags: java

Есть `List`, типа `String`, хочу вывести все элементы в одну строчку, через запятую.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Вывести на экран в одну строку или создать новый объект, где элементы в одну строку?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Начиная c  `Java 1.8` можно воспользоваться классом `StringJoiner`, `Collector`.

**Пример *StringJoiner*:**

```
 StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
 for (Item item : list) {
   joiner.add(item.toString());
 }
 String myString = joiner.toString();
```

**Пример *Collector*:**

```
String myString = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

До `Java 1.8` можно реализовать это следующим образом:

```
String delim = "";
for (int i : ints) {
  sb.append(delim).append(i);
  delim = ",";
}
```

Comment: Пример Collector удобнее

Comment: Спасибо. Все понял.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
String joined = String.join(" and ", list);  // "foo and bar and baz"
```

Либо Java 8 Stream API

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

String joinedFirstNames = list.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // "foo, bar, baz"
```